# Css ragged bottom, what does it mean?

Tags: javascript, css, masonry

Looking at the different masonry approaches out there, and specifically looking at the summary here

https://css-tricks.com/piecing-together-approaches-for-a-css-masonry-layout/

It is said: "Is vertical order with ragged bottoms OK?"

With a code pen theoretically showing this ragged bottoms, here 
https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/NeRNBO or here https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/XojXxy

But I cannot see where are the ragged bottoms

Either I need some clue, or this is an issue the browsers have already solved?

(the approach in the codepen, pure css)

```css
.masonry-with-columns {
  columns: 6 200px;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  div {
    width: 150px;
    background: #EC985A;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 1rem 1rem 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: system-ui;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 2rem;
  } 
  @for $i from 1 through 36 { 
    div:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      $h: (random(400) + 100) + px;
      height: $h;
      line-height: $h;
    }
  }
}
```

(Or the flex-based one)

```css
.masonry-with-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 1000px;
  div {
    width: 150px;
    background: #EC985A;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 1rem 1rem 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: system-ui;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 2rem;
  } 
  @for $i from 1 through 36 { 
    div:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      $h: (random(400) + 100) + px;
      height: $h;
      line-height: $h;
    }
  }
}
```

[image: codepen1]

Comment: I'm certainly seeing ragged bottoms there in chrome. The lower elements all have different lowest points, hence, ragged bottoms. What browser are you testing with?

Comment: I've updated the question to add a screenshot, probably you can also see there the ragged bottoms, but I just can't, or it is very subtle, or I don't know at where to look (?) (Chrome 80.0, windows10)

Comment: Your screenshot also indicates ragged bottoms. If it wasn't ragged, the lower points of the last row would create a straight line. Either that or I'm completely misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Ouch, at least by ragged bottoms you/they mean the elements are not ending on the same position? But this is also the case in the other solutions, so it's not this right?

Comment: Yes, then what solution does not provide ragged bottoms? I was understanding the ragged effect was for each element, a render problem or so

Comment: That is correct. JavaScript solutions can accommodate this. CSS , no one has managed that yet. This is why the CSS Tricks mentions this only works with Vertical Ordering and Ragged bottoms.

Comment: From the same article, this is an example of a nice [smooth bottom](https://css-tricks.com/piecing-together-approaches-for-a-css-masonry-layout/#article-header-id-2) . (Internal Link not working.. see the section titled *Do you need a clean bottom edge? A Flexbox/JavaScript combo can help.*

Comment: Thanks, much clearer now, I completely misunderstood the claim :) If you'd like to post this as a short answer I'll close the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the screenshot in your question demonstrates is the perfect example of ragged bottoms. In fact the linked article states you need to be OK with "Vertical Ordering and Ragged Bottoms".

Flush masonry is not currently achievable with CSS alone. A [subsequent section](https://css-tricks.com/piecing-together-approaches-for-a-css-masonry-layout/#article-header-id-2) titled *Do you need a clean bottom edge? A Flexbox/JavaScript combo can help.* demonstrates an effective hybrid approach.